# solution of a sequence in a given range

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Given an equation $$x^{\frac{1}{n}}=\sqrt{1-x}$$ has a unique solution $x_n$ in $[0,+\infty)$ for each $n \in\mathbb{N}$. One can see that $$x_n=1-x^{\frac{2}{n}}$$ But how do we show that the solutions are unique?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$f(x) = x^a$$ for some $a>0$. $f(x)$ is clearly *increasing* since $f'(x) \geq 0$ for $x\geq 0$.

Consider $$g(x) = \sqrt{1-x}$$ and see that $$g'(x) = \frac{-1}{2\sqrt{1-x}} < 0$$ for all $x\geq 0$. So $g(x)$ is *decreasing*.

Can you now conclude that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ cannot have more than one intersection? In other words, $f(x) = g(x)$ cannot have more than one solution for a fixed $a>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the domain is $x\in [0,1]$ and let $x=\sin^2 t$ to reexpress the equation as
$$\sin^{\frac2n}t = \cos t,\>\>\>\>\>t\in [0,\frac\pi2]$$
Since $\sin^{\frac2n}t $ strictly increases from 0 to 1 and $\cos t$ strictly decreases from 1 to 0, they cross each other once over $[0,\frac\pi2]$, hence a unique solution.

Comment: Apart from a change of variables, this looks exactly like my solution! :)